# How can I get key repeat to work with Vim in VSCodium

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscodevim, vscodium

I have installed VSCodium and the Vim extension from vscodevim (Mac), but I don't have any key repeat. I have tried the following terminal command, but it doesn't seem to work:

```
defaults write com.microsoft.VSCodeExploration ApplePressAndHoldEnabled -bool false
```

Key repeat is working fine in VSCode, Vim and Obsidian.

Do you know how I can try to solve this issue?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

@Kromanen, try this in the terminal :)

```
defaults write com.vscodium ApplePressAndHoldEnabled -bool false
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue, I have tried all this command multiple times restarting everything many times.

The issue was that key repetition was not enabled on my mac (Even if it was enabled on settings);

To try it just go in any page and try to press a key and see if it repeats multiple times.

If not that's the issue!!

To enable it you first have to run this command:

```
defaults write -g ApplePressAndHoldEnabled -bool false
```

Now you have to run this for normal VScode:

```
defaults write com.microsoft.VSCode ApplePressAndHoldEnabled -bool false
```

Or this for VSCode Insiders:

```
defaults write com.microsoft.VSCodeInsiders ApplePressAndHoldEnabled -bool false
```

Now you have to close VSCode totally (not using command Q) right click icon quit for me. Then reopen it and should work :)